# php code in block - Load node

Tags: 7, blocks, panels, nodes

I have previously used `<?php print $node->field_listing_artist[0]['taxonomy_term']->description; ?>` on page.tpl.php. What this does is prints the description of the related taxonomy term of the node being displayed.

But I am looking to use this piece of code in a Block or a Custom Content Type in Panels.

From searching around, I can see (I think?) that i need to load_node, but cannot seem to get the code to work.
[Similar Drupal Answers Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13152)

So what i am trying to achieve is create a block/'Panels custom content type' that will correctly process `<?php print $node->field_listing_artist[0]['taxonomy_term']->description; ?>` of the node currently being viewed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/how-does-one-create-a-new-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc), and in addition make sure the content type has a required context on nodes so that you can't accidentally render it without a node. Check the examples on the ctools module to see how to add required contexts.